# How to filter objects by objects in Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

**My First object is:**

```
 {Color: [
         {display: "RED", value: "5433", count: "12"}
         {display: "Black", value: "5446", count: "37"}    
        ]
        Brand: [
         {display: "NIKAVI", value: "5458", count: "58", brand: }
         {display: "BOSCH", value: "5570", count: "7",}
         {display: "REPLAY", value: "5497", count: "132",}
        ]
        Category: [
         {display: "Motorbike Horns", value: "1320", count: "8"}
         {display: "LED Lamps", value: "1325", count: "3"}
        ]
    }
```

**My Second object is:**

```
{Brand: "5458", Color: "5446",Category:[1320,75]}
```

I have to filter the first object value using the second objects values. I have tried a lot but couldn't find great ideas. I'm working in reactJs.

Comment: _"I have tried a lot..."_ - Please add at least the most promising one and describe which problems you have with it respectively which errors it throws.

Comment: Forget code for a second - how  would you solve it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over key-value pairs over the second object and then use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method(or use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method if you need an array or there is multiple) to get the result.

```js
const obj1 = {Color: [
         {display: "RED", value: "5433", count: "12"},
         {display: "Black", value: "5446", count: "37"}    
        ],
        Brand: [
         {display: "NIKAVI", value: "5458", count: "58", brand: ''},
         {display: "BOSCH", value: "5570", count: "7",},
         {display: "REPLAY", value: "5497", count: "132",}
        ],
        Category: [
         {display: "Motorbike Horns", value: "1320", count: "8"},
         {display: "LED Lamps", value: "1325", count: "3"}
        ]
    };

;
const obj2={Brand: "5458", Color: "5446",Category:[1320,75]};



const res = {};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
  res[key] = obj1[key].filter(o => Array.isArray(value) ? value.some(v => v == o.value) : o.value === value) 
}


console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks you answers saved my day. I have just edited my question. Could you please help with with small modifications

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Again you saved my day. May I know where u learnt such stuffs

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```js
firstObj = {Color: [
  {display: "RED", value: "5433", count: "12"},
  {display: "Black", value: "5446", count: "37"}    
 ],
 Brand: [
  {display: "NIKAVI", value: "5458", count: "58",},
  {display: "BOSCH", value: "5570", count: "7",},
  {display: "REPLAY", value: "5497", count: "132",}
 ]
};

secondObj={Brand: "5458", Color: "5446"}

// solution:
const result =Object.keys(secondObj).map(sk => firstObj[sk].filter(fo => fo.value === secondObj[sk]))
    
    
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks you answers saved my day. I have just edited my question. Could you please help with with small modifications